# Core Data on iOS -- get specific changes done to object

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

Is it possible to get the specific changes done to an object in *NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate's* `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` method?

While I'm looking for a **pretty solution**, I guess a hack would be fine too...

Thanks,
A. Dvorak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the change type, that tells you broadly what happened and covers the insert / delete / move. The only case where you need more details is on an update type. In this case, you have the object so you can call `changedValues` or `changedValuesForCurrentEvent` on it to get the required details.